# resizable simulator with various screen sizes

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm having xcode 6.0.1 and when I tried to test app on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus simulators it is working nice but when I enter the width and height values in resizable simulator and after applying those values all app screens are disturbing in resizable simulator. What is wrong, the default simulators for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus are working properly but the resizable simulator is not?

Comment: There is no need to use the resizable simulator to test since there are now actual iPhone 6 and 6+ simulators.

Comment: Yes . but my question is my app is running well in provided simulators for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus but not in resizable. Why this kind of behaviour?? which one is correct??

Comment: Real people have iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ devices, not resizable devices. As I said, don't bother using the resizable simulator any more. Use the iPhone 6 and 6+ simulators since they simulate real user devices.

Comment: You are not understanding what I want to say... Why such different behaviors is there any issue with the resizable simulator.??

Comment: The resizable simulator isn't an iPhone 6 or 6+ simulator. It behaves differently. As I've said twice already. It doesn't matter. Stop using the reliable simulator. If your app works with the actual iPhone 6/6+ simulators then that's good.

Comment: @rmaddy Do you still think this is true? My app works on all existing iPad and iPhone sizes, but breaks on non-standard sizes (e.g., 900x800). Is that fine? Personally, I'm trying to figure out what to do with "Resizable iPad." Thanks for any guidance.